# JQ: How to improve print values

Tags: jquery, bash, shell, devops, jq

I would like improve my shell script and print a good values using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) I'm get results from sonarqube api.

In using this script.

```
projectStatusUrl='url/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=app'
project_status="$(curl -s -u token: -G --data-urlencode --data-urlencode ${projectStatusUrl})"

code_T=$(jq -r '.projectStatus.conditions[] | select(.status=="ERROR") | .status,.metricKey,.comparator' <<< "$project_status")
echo "$code_T"
```

with a this script I'm getting this results

```
ERROR
new_coverage
LT
ERROR
new_duplicated_lines_density
GT
```

I would like improve this format for example add text before values.

```
Status: ERROR
MetricKey: new_coverage
Comparator: LT

Status: ERROR
MetricKey: new_duplicated_lines_density
Comparator: GT
```

I trying using this code below

```
code_T=$(jq -r '.projectStatus.conditions[] | select(.status=="ERROR") | {Status:.status, MetricKey:.metricKey,Comparator:.comparator}' <<< "$project_status")

but my result is 

{
  "Status": "ERROR",
  "MetricKey": "new_coverage",
  "Comparator": "LT"
}
{
  "Status": "ERROR",
  "MetricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density",
  "Comparator": "GT"
}
```

I would like to validate my steps using an if statements it's possible with this block code below, In my test my conditions else always true

```
code_T=$(jq -r '.projectStatus.conditions[] | select(.status) | {Status:.status, MetricKey:.metricKey,Comparator:.comparator}' <<< "$project_status")
```

```
if [[ ${code_T} == "OK" ]]; then
   echo '::set-output name=quality-status::PASSED'

elif [[ ${code_T} == "WARN" ]]; then
   echo '::set-output name=quality-status::WARN'
elif [[ ${code_T} == "ERROR" ]]; then
   echo '::set-output name=quality-status::$code_T'

else
   echo "::set-output name=quality-status::$code_T"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{Status:.status, MetricKey:.metricKey,Comparator:.comparator}` you've used creates JSON objects. What you seem to be looking for is just string concatenation:

```
"Status: " + .status, "MetricKey: " + .metricKey, "Comparator: " + .comparator
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to concatenate, but I didn't use a correct form 

Thanks very much.